# Animated film or TV episode from the 80's or earlier?

Tags: story-identification, animation

Inspired by some of the other "what was this show" type questions. It might be a long shot because I only remember a few bits of this from my early childhood, which would date it as the mid-'80s or earlier (no way of knowing if it was a new show or a repeat).

I only really remember two scenes:

1) A small group (possibly as few as two, no more than 5) are walking or running on what I think was an alien planet, amongst what looked like large green tree roots (almost like if they were miniature and running between blades of grass).

2) There was a scene where someone had died, and their coffin was ejected into space from some kind of base station. Either this scene or the first one had some very memorable music - like a pan pipe or a flute sound, fairly high pitched but quite sombre or soulful.

Not sure if this rings any bells, but I occasionally think back to it and would really like to know what the show or film was. I might be able to provide more detail if requested. I'm pretty sure it was animated (cartoon) rather than live action, but it was so long ago even that could be wrong.

Edit: additional details from comments:

- It was definitely at home on TV, so it was either a TV movie or show.
- The animation style is hard to remember. I *think* it was a bit like the He-Man animated series.
- I live in the UK so this was an English language show.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F!  This is a good question, but maybe you could add a few more details, like animation style?  Where you saw it?

Comment: Just in case, please take a look at  [these guidelines on story-ID](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/98028), see if they trigger any more memories to edit in :)

Comment: Thanks, I've taken a look and will add more detail as I think of it.

Comment: Was the small group made of humans or aliens?

Comment: I would say human but could have been a mix. Pretty sure the main characters were humanoid.

Answer (score 3):

Your description reminds me of a French movie ***[Les maîtres du temps](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Les_Ma%C3%AEtres_du_temps)*** (aired in the UK as *Time Masters*).

The story is about a boy lost in a sort of giant forest and a group of protagonists who received a distress call and come to rescue him, traversing diverse alien worlds.

At the end of the movie, there is a funeral scene that looks like the one you describe.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if it was ever aired in the UK, but somehow it makes me think of [Starblazers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space_Battleship_Yamato), a late 70s anime series

This was the main starship (Yamato or, in some western versions, Argo), in case it rings some bells

[image]

And this is the main cast of characters

[image]

There were the funerals in space, and also the soundtrack was well-suited to the more intense scenes.
Since the plot was about the titular starship traveling the space to save the Earth, there were numerous episodes where the crew had to land on alien planets, so maybe the scene you remember was from one of these episodes

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I'm not sure it's correct though, but I'd really need to find a video of the episode I remember to be sure so I'll do some more research and see what I can find

Comment: @WillAppleby any update on the above?